# How to change afterwards, the value of a Dialog.AddFieldValue?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In Axapta, i can add a field into a dialog with:

Dialog.AddFieldValue

But,Is it possible to change that value afterwards ? Maybe, when a new event is fired ?
I can't find a 'name' for that field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return value of `Dialog.addFieldValue`:

```
fld = dialog.addFieldValue(typeId(Counter), 117);
```

Later you can:

```
fld.value(118);
```